# Mentre or quando, what is the difference?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I am using Duolingo to learn Italian and I came across this translation exercise: "I eat when I want". I answered: "mangio mentre voglio". However it is marked wrong. The right answer is: "mangio quando voglio". 
Can someone please show me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Quando* means *when*
- *Mentre* means *while*.

*Would you say "I eat while I want" or "...when I want"?*

(same difference as in English)